# How can I fix the no screen error on xserver startup on Linux?

Tags: debian, drivers, nvidia, nouveau

When I try to start my Debian 9 xserver, it shows a black screen.

`Xorg -configure` outputs

> Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices

and outputs a non-working xorg.conf.

`glxinfo | grep -i vendor` outputs:

> unable to open display

I have a `nVidia GeForce GTX 745 with 4GB` and I am using the `nouveau drivers`, because Nvidia's own drivers output the same error and I wanted to set my drivers back to default. This happened after I tried to install the nVidia `nvidia-driver` packages to have better performance.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Xorg -configure`? Typo.

Comment: @Mukesh Sai Kumar fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (on a different distro, trying to install NVidia drivers, anyhow you may find some light with my solution). I fixed it by doing the following steps:

- Remove NVidia Drivers : `apt-get remove nvidia* --purge`
- Remove the bad `xorg.conf` file generated by `Xorg -configure` : `sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
- Remove a modprobe.d config file I created, which blacklisted loading of `nouveau`.

---

BTW, maybe you forgot to blacklist `nouveau`, I think you may have to blacklist it to get nvidia drivers working, at least according to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-of-nouveau). You may also try editing the xorg.conf by hand.

Comment: When I use Xorg -configure it gives me an error. I'll try installing the nVidia packages and uninstalling them again. Also: is it possible my monitor driver is missing? The errors seem to have something to do with my monitor drivers, but I'm not sure.

Comment: There is nothing as "monitor driver".